# How to enable highchart animation in jquery clone?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, clone

i am using highchart to create a graph. If i move the mouse over the graph it shows the values. This works great.

If i clone the graph using jquery there is no animation anymore. You can see it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLj6yaxc/).

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>

<div id="copyto">
</div>

<button id="button">Set new data</button>
<button id="button2">Copy</button>


$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });


    // the button action
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({data:[229.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]} );
       
    });
    
    $('#button2').click(function() {
          var $myclone = $("#wrapper").clone().prop("id", "clonewrapper");
            $("#copyto").append($myclone);
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to re-initiate highchart with cloned div

Comment: How can i re-initiate the cloned chart? No i dont need the set new data button anymore. It was for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the div you need to reinitiate `highcharts` on the cloned div

Here is a working solution:

```js
$(function() {
  createHightChart('container');
  // the button action
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].remove();
    chart.addSeries({
      data: [229.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    });

  });

  $('#button2').click(function() {
    var $myclone = $("#wrapper").clone().prop("id", "clonewrapper");
    $("#copyto").append($myclone);
    createHightChart('clonewrapper');
  });
});

function createHightChart(elementId) {
  $('#'+elementId).highcharts({
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],
    accessibility: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>

<div id="copyto">
</div>

<button id="button">Set new data</button>
<button id="button2">Copy</button>
```

**Note:** In case you want ***`Set new data`*** button to work for all chart div(s), do like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kaz6cfp1/

As per discussion you can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mws5pug1/

Comment: Thanks it works but is it possible to use the options from the chart without creating a function? I tried this: jsfiddle.net/57f6cr1b/1 but it wont work as expectet. The first chart will be deletet.

Comment: @user6625547 yes you can do like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mws5pug1/

Comment: @user6625547  "If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the second chart by using user options from the first one. For example:

```
  $('#button2').click(function() {
    var options = $('#container').highcharts().userOptions;
    $("#copyto").highcharts(options);
  });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qheuLb1k/

Comment: I need to clone the div because there is much more text. But if i am cloning it it will be remove the first chart: https://jsfiddle.net/57f6cr1b/1/

Comment: Hi @user6625547, You need to remove the cloned chart container and create a new one, because it keeps a chart reference. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/snybfg5t/